# jQuery form Validation does not include value of submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm using jquery form validation from http://www.runningcoder.org/jqueryvalidation/

demo.html

```
<form id="form-signup_v1" name="form-signup_v1" method="get" class="validation-form-container">
<div class="field">
    <label for="signup_v1-username">First Name</label>
    <div class="ui left labeled input">
        <input id="first_name" name="first_name" type="text">
        <div class="ui corner label">
            <i class="asterisk icon">*</i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<input name="ok" id="ok" type="submit" class="ui blue submit button" value="Ok">
<input name="cancel" id="cancel" type="submit" class="ui blue submit button" value="Cancel">
</form>

<script>
$('#form-signup_v1').validate({
    submit: {
        settings: {
            inputContainer: '.field'
        }
    }
});
</script>
```

I'm use form validation in the url not include the value of submit button

```
demo.html?first_name=John
```

[image]

I try to remove jquery form validation in the url include the value of submit button

```
demo.html?first_name=John&ok=OK
```

[image]

I want to check submit button when click from query string but when i use validation the url alway not include query string of button like the figure 1

Comment: First of all check this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please add more info, clearing in question

Comment: <form action="" action="get">  there are two action attribute this bad practice.

Comment: sory my english is bad

Answer (score 0):

If you want that the query doesn't include the button name just remove the name attribute from `<input type = "button" name="ok">`. Also assign a value to the button. By default the submit action forms the query string from the name value pairs in the form.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="get">
    <input name="first_name" type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="button">
</form>
```